# How to change the font of TWTweetComposeViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, twitter

Hello i am trying to tweet from my iOS App.

In iOS5 , We can use `Twitter Framework`.

So i write following code to tweet.

```
if([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {

        TWTweetComposeViewController *controller = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [controller setInitialText:self.txtView.text];
        controller.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result)  {

            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

            switch (result) {
                case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                    break;

                case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        };

        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
```

I can tweet with above code. But i have my custom font in my app.

So my tweet with custom font is like following pic.

[image]

So can i change the font of `TWTweetComposeViewController`?
If it can be , how can i change it?

Answer (score 0):

No you can not change the font of TWTweetComposeViewController.

Comment: So is there any others way to do it?